# How to set multi-level test setup/teardown in robot framework

Tags: testing, automated-tests, robotframework, teardown

I have some robot test cases separated in directories. The directory hierarchy is:

```
ParentTestDirectory
    |__ ChidTestDirectoryOne
        |__ TestOne.robot
    |__ ChidTestDirectoryTwo
        |__ TestTwo.robot
    |__ __init__.robot
```

Content of `__init__.robot`:

```
*** Settings ***
Test Setup          LOG TO CONSOLE   Test setup from __init__.robot
Test Teardown       LOG TO CONSOLE   Test teardown from __init__.robot
```

Content of `TestOne.robot`:

```
*** Settings ***
Test Setup          LOG TO CONSOLE   Test setup from TestOne.robot
Test Teardown       LOG TO CONSOLE   Test teardown from TestOne.robot
*** Test Cases ***
Test One
    LOG TO CONSOLE   This is Test One!
```

Content of `TestTwo.robot`:

```
*** Settings ***
Test Setup          LOG TO CONSOLE   Test setup from TestTwo.robot
Test Teardown       LOG TO CONSOLE   Test teardown from TestTwo.robot
*** Test Cases ***
Test Two
    LOG TO CONSOLE   This is Test Two!
```

I have a runner written in python which uses robot runner module; this is the result of running test cases with command `sudo python run.py --testsuit scenarios.ParentTestDirectory`:

```
==============================================================================
Scenarios                                                                     
==============================================================================
Scenarios.ParentTestDirectory                                                 
==============================================================================
Scenarios.ParentTestDirectory.ChidTestDirectoryOne                            
==============================================================================
Scenarios.ParentTestDirectory.ChidTestDirectoryOne.TestOne                    
==============================================================================
Test One                                                              Test setup from TestOne.robot
.This is Test One!
.Test teardown from TestOne.robot
Test One                                                              | PASS |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Scenarios.ParentTestDirectory.ChidTestDirectoryOne.TestOne            | PASS |
1 critical test, 1 passed, 0 failed
1 test total, 1 passed, 0 failed
==============================================================================
Scenarios.ParentTestDirectory.ChidTestDirectoryOne                    | PASS |
1 critical test, 1 passed, 0 failed
1 test total, 1 passed, 0 failed
==============================================================================
Scenarios.ParentTestDirectory.ChidTestDirectoryTwo                            
==============================================================================
Scenarios.ParentTestDirectory.ChidTestDirectoryTwo.TestTwo                    
==============================================================================
Test Two                                                              Test setup from TestTwo.robot
.This is Test Two!
.Test teardown from TestTwo.robot
Test Two                                                              | PASS |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Scenarios.ParentTestDirectory.ChidTestDirectoryTwo.TestTwo            | PASS |
1 critical test, 1 passed, 0 failed
1 test total, 1 passed, 0 failed
==============================================================================
Scenarios.ParentTestDirectory.ChidTestDirectoryTwo                    | PASS |
1 critical test, 1 passed, 0 failed
1 test total, 1 passed, 0 failed
==============================================================================
Scenarios.ParentTestDirectory                                         | PASS |
2 critical tests, 2 passed, 0 failed
2 tests total, 2 passed, 0 failed
==============================================================================
Scenarios                                                             | PASS |
2 critical tests, 2 passed, 0 failed
2 tests total, 2 passed, 0 failed
==============================================================================
```

As you see, it just runs the latest test setup/teardown. I want it to run test setups/teardowns from parent directories too and it should be executed prior to child's. In other words I want the parent setup to be run for each test case separately before it's own setup. Can I achieve this with robot framework capabilities?

Comment: Do you want the parent setup only run once, before all the child test cases are started? If so, consider using `Suite Setup` and `Suite Teardown` in your `__init__.robot`.  Or do you want the parent setup to be run for each test case separately before it's own setup?

Comment: @A.Kootstra, your second guess is true. I want the parent setup to be run for each test case separately before it's own setup.

Comment: When the second option is what you're looking for, then the answer of @Brian Oakley is the correct one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A test case can only have a single setup. When you put `Test Setup` in the settings for a suite as a whole, that defines a *default* test setup. If a child suite or an individual test defines a test setup, it will be run *instead* of the suite level setup defined higher up.

In the section titled [Initialization files](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#initialization-files) in the robot framework user guide, it says this (with emphasis added by me):

> *Test Setup, Test Teardown, Test Timeout*
>
> Set the **default** value for test setup/teardown or test timeout to all test cases this directory contains. **Can be overridden on lower level.** Support for defining test timeout in initialization files was added in Robot Framework 2.7.

If you want the suite to define a test setup that is run in addition to the setup specified by each test, you should put that code into a custom keyword and let each test call that keyword as part of its setup.