# How can I control log level of plain-text debug files in robot framework?

Tags: logging, robotframework, logfile, log-level

I have read [this documentation](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#debug-file) which explains how to create plain-text log files during execution. As it says it is a `Debug File` and `All messages got from test libraries are written to them`; but I'm looking for a way to control the log level of its content. Isn't there any mechanism or trick to obtain that? Or even any other robot framework option which also have the functionality of `Debug file` (writing test execution messages to a plain-text while test is in progress)?

Comment: Have you seen `--loglevel <option>`? I have never used it so I don't know if it is applied to the debug file or just the log file (possibly just the log file TBH but worth a shot. http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#log-levels

Comment: I've no experience with this Debug file as well, but you can create easily your own custom log using Listener interface: http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#listener-interface
I would say it's worthy to explore and try.

Comment: @Goralight, the `--loglevel` option is used for setting log level of HTML report and log files. I tested it; it doesn't apply on the debug file.

Comment: @ZeinabAbbasi Thought so, was just throwing it at you to see if it would work. I don't think RF has something like that built in I'm afraid then :(

Comment: @JanKovařík, thanks for the link, but unfortunately it doesn't fit my need. `Listeners` can be adapted to implement specific actions when an event happens; for example when a suite starts, specified `Listeners` get a message about it and if they have implemented some actions for `start_suite`, it will be executed. No controlling on the log level of output files is provided other than what is provided in runner right now.

Comment: Did you see `message` and `log_message` methods?

Comment: @JanKovařík, yes, I did. I want to control log level of `Debug file`; which means I want to tell robot runner what level should be written in `Debug file`. It can't be accomplished by  `message` and `log_message`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to control the amount of detail that goes into the debug file. The whole point of the debug file is to create a detailed output for debugging purposes.

If you want information to be written to a plain text file as the test is running, you can create a [listener](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#listener-interface) that writes whatever you want, whenever you want.

For example, lets say you want to write the time that each test starts and ends. The first step would be to create a listener. For this example, create a file named "CustomLog.py" with the following contents:

```
import datetime
class CustomLog:
    ROBOT_LISTENER_API_VERSION = 2

    def __init__(self, filename='listen.txt'):
        self.logfile = open("/tmp/robot.log", 'w')

    def _write(self, message):
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        self.logfile.write(str(now) + " " + message + "\n")
        self.logfile.flush()

    def start_test(self, name, attrs):
        self._write("start_test: %s" % name)

    def end_test(self, name, attrs):
        self._write("end_test: %s (%s)" % (name, attrs["status"]))

    def close(self):
        self.logfile.close()
```

You can pass the name of this file to robot via the `--listener` argument:

```
robot --listener CustomLog.py ...
```

The listener interface gives you the ability to perform actions which suites, tests, and keywords start and stop. These methods are all covered in the documentation.

Comment: It also helped me solve [this issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43438551/how-to-set-multi-level-test-setup-teardown-in-robot-framework).